# How to insert bulk data in Google App Engine Datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have some CSV files for cities,state and countries with their ids, names etc. I want to put all this data into Google app engine datastore.

Can someone please suggest an efficient way of doing this on development server as well as on the production server?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in luck.  The functionality you described is baked into appcfg.py:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html