# How to upload data in bulk to the appengine datastore? Older methods do not work

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

This should be a fairly common requirement, and a simple process: upload data in bulk to the appengine datastore.

However, none of the older solutions mentioned on stackoverflow (links below*) seem to work anymore. The bulkloader method, which was the most reasonable solution when uploading to the datastore using the DB API doesn't work with the NDB API

And now the bulkloader method seems to have been deprecated  and the old links, which are still present in the docs, lead to the wrong page. Here's an example

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata

This above link is still present on this page: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp

What is the recommended method for bulkloading data now?

The two feasible alternatives seem to be 1) using the remote_api or 2) writing a CSV file to a GCS bucket and reading from that. Anybody have experience successfully using either method?

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[*The solutions offered at the links below are no longer valid]

[1] [how does one upload data in bulk to a google appengine datastore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741599/how-does-one-upload-data-in-bulk-to-a-google-appengine-datastore)

[2] [How to insert bulk data in Google App Engine Datastore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618147/how-to-insert-bulk-data-in-google-app-engine-datastore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of you might be in my situation: I cannot use the import/export utility of datastore, because my data needs to be transformed before getting into the datastore.

I ended up using **[apache-beam](https://beam.apache.org/) ([google cloud dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/))**.

You only need to write a few lines of "beam" code to

- read your data (for example, hosted on cloud storage) - you get a `PCollection` of strings,
- do whatever transform you want (so you get a `PCollection` of datastore Entities),
- dump them to [datastore sink](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/datastore/v1/datastoreio.py).

See [How to speedup bulk importing into google cloud datastore with multiple workers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50205956/how-to-speedup-bulk-importing-into-google-cloud-datastore-with-multiple-workers) for a concrete use case.

I was able to write with a speed of 800 entities per second into my datastore with 5 workers. This enabled me to finish the importing task (with 16 million rows) in about 5 hours. If you want to make it faster, use more workers :D

Comment: please fix broken link

Answer (score 10):

**Method 1: Use remote_api**

**How to** : write a *bulkloader.yaml* file and run it directly using “*appcfg.py upload_data*” command from terminal
I don’t recommend this method for a couple of reasons: 1. huge latency 2. no support for NDB

**Method 2: GCS and use mapreduce**

**Uploading Data File to GCS:**

Use the “[storage-file-transfer-json-python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-file-transfer-json-python)” github project (chunked_transfer.py) to upload files to gcs from your local system. 
Make sure to generate proper “client-secrets.json” file from the app engine admin console.

**Mapreduce:**

Use the "[appengine-mapreduce](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-mapreduce)" github project. Copy the "mapreduce" folder to your project top-level folder.

Add the below line to your app.yaml file:

```
includes:
  - mapreduce/include.yaml
```

Below is your main.py file

```
import cgi
import webapp2
import logging
import os, csv
from models import DataStoreModel
import StringIO
from google.appengine.api import app_identity
from mapreduce import base_handler
from mapreduce import mapreduce_pipeline
from mapreduce import operation as op
from mapreduce.input_readers import InputReader

def testmapperFunc(newRequest):
    f = StringIO.StringIO(newRequest)
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        newEntry = DataStoreModel(attr1=row[0], link=row[1])
        yield op.db.Put(newEntry)

class TestGCSReaderPipeline(base_handler.PipelineBase):
    def run(self, filename):
        yield mapreduce_pipeline.MapreducePipeline(
                "test_gcs",
                "testgcs.testmapperFunc",
                "mapreduce.input_readers.FileInputReader",
                mapper_params={
                    "files": [filename],
                    "format": 'lines'
                },
                shards=1)

class tempTestRequestGCSUpload(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        bucket_name = os.environ.get('BUCKET_NAME',
                                     app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name())

        bucket = '/gs/' + bucket_name
        filename = bucket + '/' + 'tempfile.csv'

        pipeline = TestGCSReaderPipeline(filename)
        pipeline.with_params(target="mapreducetestmodtest")
        pipeline.start()
        self.response.out.write('done')

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/gcsupload', tempTestRequestGCSUpload),
], debug=True)
```

*To remember:*

1. Mapreduce project uses the now-deprecated “Google Cloud Storage Files API”. So support in future is not guaranteed.
2. Map reduce adds a small overhead to datastore reads and writes.

**Method 3: GCS and GCS Client Library**

1. Upload the csv/text file to gcs using the above file-transfer method.
2. Use gcs client library (copy the 'cloudstorage' folder to your application top-level folder).

Add the below code to the application main.py file.

```
import cgi
import webapp2
import logging
import jinja2
import os, csv
import cloudstorage as gcs
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.api import app_identity
from models import DataStoreModel

class UploadGCSData(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        bucket_name = os.environ.get('BUCKET_NAME',
                                     app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name())
        bucket = '/' + bucket_name
        filename = bucket + '/tempfile.csv'
        self.upload_file(filename)

    def upload_file(self, filename):
        gcs_file = gcs.open(filename)
        datareader = csv.reader(gcs_file)
        count = 0
        entities = []
        for row in datareader:
            count += 1
                newProd = DataStoreModel(attr1=row[0], link=row[1])
                entities.append(newProd)

            if count%50==0 and entities:
                ndb.put_multi(entities)
                entities=[]

        if entities:
            ndb.put_multi(entities)

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/gcsupload', UploadGCSData),
], debug=True)
```

Comment: Method 3 will timeout for lots of data, unless you split your BIG CSVs.

Comment: @sh4dydud3_88 yes. That is the reason why i prefer the mapreduce method for large amount of data. Also splitting the CSVs into chunks of 20k entities per CSV also works just fine.

Comment: Seems a bit silly to talk about uploading files to GCS using a python script when there is `gsutil` which makes it as easy as a `cp` command in the terminal.

Comment: Does a person need to include the mapreduce.yaml and queue.yaml files when going with solution #2?

Comment: Just download the mapreduce folder from github and copy the entire directory inside your project root folder

Answer (score 3):

The remote API method, as demonstrated in your link [1], still works fine - although it is very slow if you have more than a few hundred rows.

I have successfully used GCS in conjunction with the MapReduce framework to download, rather than upload, the contents of the datastore, but the principles should be the same. See the [mapreduce documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/mapreduce_library): in fact you only need the mapper step, so you can define a simple function which accepts a row from your CSV and creates a datastore entity from that data.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. We are looking into this method now; will post an update here on how it goes.

Comment: @Cygorger, Did you get anywhere following mapreduce path? I'm new to GAE, I'd like to import some data from existing system to datastore so that I can start playing with it but I have no idea where to start for uploading my data.

Comment: @opensourcegeek The method posted by sriram works. Hope that helps!

Comment: That documentation link above is from 2014, one wonders if it still pertains in 2017.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2018 the best way to go about this is to use [the new import/export capability](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities).

Comment: I've read that document a couple times and I'm still confused.  It seems that it is designed solely for importing previously exported data.  How do I format data for import?  That doesn't seem to be explained on that page.

If that isn't the case, could you point me towards an example of how to upload a CSV/TSV file into DataStore?

Comment: @Jared Nedzel, I was in the the same situation as you. See my answer which might help you too.